# How to return object of private inner class object java

Tags: java, inner-classes

How can I return the object of a private inner class

```
public class MainClass{
   public InnerClass getObj(){
       return this.new InnerClass()
   }
   private class InnerClass{
       InnerClass(){
       }
   }
}
-------------
MainClass mc = new MainClass();
mc.getObj(); // assume I am not holding it anywhere.
```

The above code is giving a null pointer exception, when I checked with the `try-catch` blocks.
Also, when tried in debug mode, its says '`ClassNotFoundException`'

But I can see the class file generated as MainClass$InnerClass.class

Comment: I can see that the constructor of the InnerClass is not being called.
I tried changing access modifier to public/none, its still same behaviour

Comment: The return type of `getObj()` is set to `void` so you won't be able to return anything. What should the correct return type be?

Comment: Thanks for pointing, i edited the code, its InnerClass

Comment: Write a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for us and post it.

Comment: There was actually, some mistake in the code, I thought it was some access related to InnerClass, but after doing a proper debugging, the issue is some thing else.
if I provided the actual code, it would have been easier, but.. its clear now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, I'm not having that same problem.  Here's my modified version of your code:

```
class MainClass {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        MainClass mc = new MainClass();
        InnerClass ic = mc.getObj();
        System.out.println( ic );
    }

    public InnerClass getObj() {
        return this.new InnerClass();
    }

    private class InnerClass {
        InnerClass() {}
    }
}
```

The result of this code is:

```
MainClass$InnerClass@64c3c749
```

Comment: I'm not sure why its not working in my project(little diff code), but your code when i copied and ran, its working fine..
I will try to edit the question properly (after reviewing), if not.. will mark yours correct.

Comment: In this case `main` can see the `private` type since it is in the same class. If `main` were in a different class it would *not* work

Answer (score 1):

As others have already pointed out all you need to do is fix the return type of your method.

However, you should be aware that you'll get a warning since you're exporting a non-public type in a public method.

Comment: he complains of a NullPointerException, which cannot arise as the result of marking 'void' a method which contains a 'return'.  This is because the 'void'/'return' conflict is a compile-time error, and NullPointerException is a runtime exception.  How could he get a runtime exception if his posted code can't get past compiletime?  The intuitive answer is: he posted the wrong code, the 'void'/'return' problem does not exist in his actual codebase, and his problem still remains. :)

Comment: Quite right! However, with the flood of answers that were coming in, I at least wanted to bring attention to the fact that the provided example code is exposing non-public types in a public API. We really can't debug and help if wrong code is posted. +1 for this and +1 for SSCCE

Answer (score 1):

Since your `getObj()` is public, you should either keep the inner class private and return an `Object`, or make it public and return an `InnerClass`, depending on your needs.

The following code returns an object in example:

```
public class MainClass {
        private class InnerClass {
                InnerClass() { System.out.println("InnerClass"); }
        }

        public Object getObj(){
                return new InnerClass();
        }

        public static void main (String[] argc) {
                MainClass a = new MainClass();
                System.out.println(a.getObj());
        }
}
```

It prints out:

```
bash-4.2$ java MainClass
InnerClass
MainClass$InnerClass@53c059f6
```

As you can see there are no problems with the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot the return type of your getObj method.

```
 public InnerClass getObj(){return new InnerClass();}
```

Comment: edited it, but return new InnerClass() will not work,
this.new InnerClass() must be used.